# Dumbass or idiot?

Tags: slang, offensive-language

Why choose dumbass instead of idiot or viceversa?

Comment: Only an idiot would call someone a dumbass.

Comment: @TRomano that's epic!

Comment: Idiot is **more formal** than dumbass, but both have the same general meaning.

Comment: You need to include your own research and context where the words would be used. Leaving out "Hi, dudes I'm an Italian with a question" and "Thank you and reply is really appreciated", you have only "Why choose dumbass instead of idiot or viceversa?" left. Have you visited our Help Center? I recommend it.

Comment: @TRomano: And only a real [*dumbass idiot*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dumbass+idiot%22) would call someone a *moron*. The vernacular of the intellectually-challenged is complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are nasty things to call someone. Call someone by either name and they are unlikely to laugh it off: you have just started an argument. I'd advise against calling your boss or a policeman by either name.

As with any harsh words, if you say it in a joking way to someone who's a good friend and who knows you're joking, it might be taken in that spirit. But if you're just learning English, I'd avoid saying things that could be taken wrong.

Besides that, the meaning of the two is pretty similar. Both are saying that the other person is of low intelligence. "Dumbass" is less formal and harsher.

If you want a milder insult, you might say, "You are being foolish" or "Are you sure you have thought about this carefully", rather than "You are an idiot".

Of course if your point is to be very nasty, if you're angry and/or the other person has just made a harsh insult to you, then these could be the words you want to use.

Comment: Thank you that explains it at all, I've asked it as I would joke with my friends :)

Comment: Let me add, I have a tendency to use insults as humor, and every now and then people take it wrong. Either they don't realize I'm joking or the joke is too close to something they're sensitive about. In one case a co-worker was mad at me for literally years over a joke she took seriously. So this is more etiquette than English, but: Be VERY careful about this kind of humor. ...

Comment: ... If everyone else in the gang is calling each other an idiot and ugly and a slut, you can join in. But I wouldn't be the one to start with that kind of humor -- especially if you don't know the language well and may something that's harsher than what you had in mind.

Comment: yes we usually insult us together :)

Comment: @HAlexTM - You've put some interesting tags on your question. I'll add this footnote: although these terms are largely used as interchangeable insults nowadays (oftentimes playfully so), that wasn't the case a hundred years ago. See [this blog post](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/03/the-words-moron-imbecile-and-idiot-mean-different-things/) and [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imbecile) for more details. It might be good to know some history behind some of the words you are tossing around.

Comment: @J.R. you're right